# Selenium find_element_by_css_selector not finding element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a personal project to automate the joining of a Twitch channel through Selenium using Python.  This is my first time using Selenium and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

When joining a channel that is flagged as containing mature content, it requires a user to click a button to start watching the stream.  My program works great until the button needs to be clicked.

The HTML for button appears as:

```
<button class="ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonPrimary-sc-1qn4ixc-1 jnsGXs ksFrFH" data-a-target="player-overlay-mature-accept"><div class="ScCoreButtonLabel-sc-lh1yxp-0 evtFDZ"><div data-a-target="tw-core-button-label-text" class="Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0 eZactg">Start Watching</div></div></button>
```

Since the class name appear to be dynamically generated, I planned on the using the "data-a-target" as the selector.  Looking at Selenium's docs, it appeared that the find_element_by_css_selector function is what I need to use.  I played around in the Chrome developer tools and was about to select the button using: `document.querySelector('button[data-a-target="player-overlay-mature-accept"]')`, so I was confident that it would work with Selenium.

I made the selection in my code with Selenium using the following code:

```
mature = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-a-target="player-overlay-mature-accept"]')
```

Unfortunately, Selenium doesn't seem to be able to find it and returns the error message:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-a-target="player-overlay-mature-accept"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

Am I doing something blatantly wrong?  I've spent a good amount of time trying different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your code seems right. maybe the button is inside an `iframe` tag? Are you able to share the link or the html source page?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
mature = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-a-target='player-overlay-mature-accept']")
```

or

```
mature = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@data-a-target, 'mature')]")
```